# open Instagram hashtag intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

For opening an specific image in Instagram i use this intent:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/p/IMAGE_ID");
Intent insta = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

if i want to see an specific hashtag all images what i have to do? Actually i want to open Instagram and see images of an hashtag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://instagram.com/explore/tags/your_tag/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```